# Exporting documents from Exact Online for one division gives a spreadsheet instead of separate files

Tags: sql, exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-control

Using the following SQL I get a list of documents and small thumbnails in Exact Online:

```
select document_account_name
       || document_references_yourref
       || year(document_date) || '-' || month(document_date) || '-' || day(document_date)
       || '.pdf'
       pdffilename
,      binarydata
from   exactonlinexml..documentattachments
where  document_documenttype_number_attr = 20
and    lower(name) like '%pdf'
```

When I try to export document from `ExactOnlineXML..Documents` using Invantive Control, I get a spreadsheet or text file with the file names and the contents when I execute:

```
local export results as "c:\export\dump.csv" format csv
```

However, I want to dump the actual file contents. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What SQL query do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps you have to follow.

First, you have to specify where to save the documents. You might also need to create a folder to store them in:

```
local define dctoutpath "${system:userdesktopdirectory}\invantive-control-for-exact-online\downloads"

local create directory "${dctoutpath}\HID\${dctdescription}"
```

Then you get the document *attachments* from Exact Online. You can do that through the [`DocumentAttachments`](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinexml-xml-documentattachments.html) table available in the Exact Online XML web service. (If you are using the combined provider you need the prefix `ExactOnlineXML..` here)

```
select binarydata
,      name
from   ExactOnlineXML..DocumentAttachments
```

Eventually you export the files through:

```
local export documents in binarydata to "${dctoutpath}\HID\${dctdescription}" filename column name
```

Note that `binarydata` and `name` have to match the fields you saved from your previous query. (According to your edit: instead of `name` you need `pdffilename` here)

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to apply the server-side filters on the combined Exact Online SQL provider? It now only seems to work with the Exact Online XML only SQL provider.

Comment: Several server-side filters on exact online xml have been included as additional views, such as BalancLlinesprocessed. The more filter-like server-side fields are not yet available with the combined provider. They are harder to add because the combined provider has a strict sql implementation.